# Selecting first 5 rows of selection after reverse sorting using attribute field in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor, select

I have a feature class containing 380 polygons representing sedimentary basins and another polygon feature class representing oil discoveries within said basins. My plan is to:

- Iterate through all basins and select all fields that fall within them.
- Reverse sort by a oil recoverable volume attribute (largest to smallest).
- Sub-select the first 5 rows of the selection and export this to a feature class (other rows will be appended).

The first two steps I think I am ok with however, I'm stuck on how I would go about creating the sub-set where the first 5 rows are selected and then exported. If there are <5 rows, all will be selected, if there are 0 rows they will be ignored.

How, using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2, can I achieve the goal of selecting the first 5 rows of a selection?

The da.SearchCursor can be used to sort but not sure after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not seeing your code, this may not work for you, but you can try to use the Python list selector:

```
for row in sorted(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [f1, f2]))[:5]
```